# Conditional output of form elements in a Razor conditional block

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, syntax, conditional-statements

This works:

```
@if (ViewBag.SkipPhone == null)
{
     <span>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone)</span>
     <span>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone)</span>
     <span>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)</span>
}
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
@if (ViewBag.SkipPhone == null)
{
                Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone);
                Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone);
                Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone);                
}
```

I understand the HTML helpers output strings, which is why the second one doesn't work.  But is there a proper way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: what is it about the second one you want? The lack of span tags?

Answer (score 2):

This one should work...

```
@if (ViewBag.SkipPhone == null)
{
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)              
}
```

You're missing @ before each line and you're adding semicolons in this case (no need for them) as Andrew Barber commented bellow...

I have code like this in my views and they do work as expected...

Comment: The semicolons probably were not meant to be included.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: you're absolutely right! Completely overlooked them as always when trying to find where the error lies... hehehe :)